# I am trying to make a expense calculator in C++ and I get this error error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Tags: c++

I am having trouble getting the code to run properly any help would be very appreciated and grateful for. I am getting error:

```
C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

In this piece of code:

```
totalBills (bills);
cout<<endl<<" Enter 1 for payments or 0 to end ";
cin>> bill;
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void totalBills (double bills, double bill1, double bill2, double bill3, double bill4,       double bill5);
void totalPayments (double payment, double payment1, double payment2, double payment3 );


void main()
{
double bill = 0.0;
double payments = 0.0;
double totalBills = 0.0;
double bills = 0.0;
cout<< "Enter 1 to set bills or zero to end: ";
cin>> bill;

while (bill > 0);
{
 totalBills (bills);
 cout<<endl<<" Enter 1 for payments or 0 to end ";
 cin>> bill;

}




system("pause");
}


void totalBills (double bills, double bill1, double bill2, double bill3, double bill4, double bill5)
{
cout<< "What is bill 1: ";
cin>> bill1 ;
cout<< "what is bill 2: ";
cin>> bill2 ;
cout<< "What is bill 3: ";
cin>> bill3 ;
cout<< "What is bill 4: ";
cin>> bill4 ;
cout<< "What is bill 5: ";
cin>> bill5 ;

bills=bill1+bill2+bill3+bill4+bill5;
}

void totalPayments (double payments, double payment1, double payment2, double payment3 )
{
cout<< "What is payment 1: ";
cin>> payment1;
cout<< "What is payment 2: ";
cin>> payment2;
cout<< "What is payment 2: ";
cin>> payment3;

payments=payment1+payment2+payment3;

}
```

Comment: The code declares totalBills() to take a bunch of arguments but only passes it one.

Comment: Your declaration of the variable `totalBiils` hides the declaration of the function `totalBills`. *And* `totalBills` takes 6 parameters - for some reason, you should probably use local variables instead - not one.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
void totalBills (double bills, double bill1, double bill2, double bill3, double bill4, double bill5)
{
cout<< "What is bill 1: ";
cin>> bill1 ;
cout<< "what is bill 2: ";
cin>> bill2 ;
cout<< "What is bill 3: ";
cin>> bill3 ;
cout<< "What is bill 4: ";
cin>> bill4 ;
cout<< "What is bill 5: ";
cin>> bill5 ;

bills=bill1+bill2+bill3+bill4+bill5;
}
```

to

```
double totalBills ()
{
double bill1, bill2, bill3, bill4, bill5, bills;
cout<< "What is bill 1: ";
cin>> bill1 ;
cout<< "what is bill 2: ";
cin>> bill2 ;
cout<< "What is bill 3: ";
cin>> bill3 ;
cout<< "What is bill 4: ";
cin>> bill4 ;
cout<< "What is bill 5: ";
cin>> bill5 ;

bills=bill1+bill2+bill3+bill4+bill5;

return bills;
}
```

and

```
totalBills (bills);
```

to

```
bills = totalBills();
```

Comment: I changed the above and its still saying error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments